# Can't start up Ubuntu after restarting to complete installation

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, uefi, usb-installation

I'm trying to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04.1 alongside Windows 10 (with UEFI).  I've tried and failed three times, and I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

**The problem I'm having is that after successfully installing Ubuntu and restarting my laptop, the Grub menu still gives me the same options that I had before: Install Ubuntu, Try Ubuntu without installing, etc.**

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Partition 100GB of unallocated space on my hard drive with the built-in Disk Management tool
2. Download Ubuntu and create a quickboot USB using Rufus
3. Disable Windows Fastboot via the UEFI menu
4. Select the quickboot USB as the first startup selection.  The grub menu appears now when I restart my laptop.  From there, I select the "Install Ubuntu" option.  At this point, I am at the Ubuntu installation menu.
5. I connect to the internet and select the options "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" and "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, Flash, MP3, and other media".
6. On the ["Installation type"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh3pu.png) menu, I choose the "Something else" option so that I can create a swap, home, and root partition.
7. In the ["Something else" menu, where I can view partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8cy.png) (not my screenshot), using the 100GB of unallocated space I partitioned earlier in Windows, I first create a new partition of size 16GB for use as swap space. The options I use for this partition are

   - Size: 16384MB (16GB)
   - Type for the new partition: Primary
   - Location for the new partition: Beginning of this space
   - Use as: swap area
8. Then I create a partition from the same unallocated space for the root file system.  I use the following options:

   - Size: 71680MB (70GB)
   - Type for the new partition: Logical
   - Location for the new partition: Beginning of this space
   - Use as: Ext4 journaling file system
   - Mount point: /
9. Finally, using the same unallocated space, I create another partition for /home.  I use the following options:

   - Size: 10240MB (10GB)
   - Type for the new partition: Logical
   - Location for this partition: Beginning of this space
   - Use as: Ext4 journaling file system
   - Mount point: /home
   - When I am done making partitions, in the "Installation type" menu, under the "Device for boot loader installation:" option, I have selected `/dev/sda [hard drive name]`
10. I then press "Install Now", which gives me a prompt saying that it will use the three partitions that I created.  I click OK and it starts installing Ubuntu
11. Ubuntu installs successfully and prompts me that I need to restart my laptop.  I click OK and my laptop restarts.  The Grub menu appears, but my options are the same as before I installed Ubuntu:

    - Install Ubuntu
    - Try Ubuntu without installing
    - Scan hard drive for errors
      [One other option here that I can't remember, but I know it does not have any relevance to the situation]

---

I've tried changing the first startup selection in the UEFI menu back to Hard Disk (windows boot), but that just goes straight to Windows 10.

**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?**

Sorry for the long post -- I wanted to make sure that I provided any and all helpful information.  Let me know if there's any other information needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the installation media? Ubuntu also does have a prompt for that.

Comment: i guess @JGut forget to remove the USB-installation media

Comment: @mikewhatever ryanw Thanks for the quick replies.  I'm note sure I understand.  Remove the USB after installation?  Or remove certain files on the USB?  I don't remember seeing any sort of prompt for removing installation media.

Comment: maybe you forgot for **unplug** your usb drive that used for installation Ubuntu. just unplug and reboot. and then see what's happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After successful installation of the Ubuntu, unplug the USB drive that you used for installation. Reboot your system and then see what happens.

Right now I only understand that your USB is bootable, and that is why your system again accesses the same process and you get the same options that you had before: Install Ubuntu, Try Ubuntu without installing, etc.

Comment: Yeah i think this might be the problem. It's especially common with virtual machines.